# building a hash from a string

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have the below string on perl :

```
my $string = xyz;1;xyz;2;a;2;b;2
```

i want to build a hash after for this string like below :

```
my @array =split /;/,$string;

$hash{xyz} =(1,2);
$hash{b}=(2);
$hahs{a}=(2);
```

what is the perl way to do this?

Comment: If you didn't have repeated keys, this would be trivial: `my %hash = split /;/, $string;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $string = "xyz;1;xyz;2;a;2;b;2";
my %hash;
push @{$hash{$1}}, $2 while $string =~ s/^(\w+);(\d+);?//g;
```

Actually

```
push @{$hash{$1}}, $2 while $string =~ m/(\w+);(\d+);?/g;
```

would be better, since that doesn't eat up your original string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the multiple values for the same key to be an array reference, then one way to do it is like this:

```
my @values = split /;/, $string;

my %hash;
while( @values ) { 
    my $key = shift @values;
    my $val = shift @values;

    if ( exists $hash{$key} && !ref $hash{$key} ) { 
        # upgrade to arrayref
        $hash{$key} = [ $hash{$key}, $val ];
    } elsif ( ref $hash{$key} ) { 
        push @{ $hash{$key} }, $val;
    } else { 
        $hash{$key} = $val;
    }
}
```

With your data, this will result in a structure like

```
    {
      'a' => '2',
      'b' => '2',
      'xyz' => [
                 '1',
                 '2'
               ]
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Drats: You have repeating keys... I wanted to do something with `map` or `grep`.

This is fairly simple to understand:

```
my $string = "xyz;1;xyz;2;a;2;b;2";
my @array = split /;/ => $string;

my %hash;
while (@array) {
    my ($key, $value) = splice @array, 0, 2;
    $hash{$key} = [] if not exists $hash{$key};
    push @{$hash{$key}}, $value;
}
```

This program will work even if the key is not together in your string. For example, the following will work even though `xyz` is separated by the other value pairs:

```
my $string = "xyz;1;a;2;b;2;xyz;2";
```

I am assuming that `$hash{b}=(2);` means you want the value of `$hash{b}` to be a reference to a single member array. Is that correct?

Comment: You don't actually need the line `$hash{$key} = [] if not exists $hash{$key};` at all.  Perl will [autovivify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) the arrayref for you when you push the first value onto it.

Comment: Also, you can do `my ($key, $value) = splice @array, 0, 2;` instead of two `shift`s.  Oh, and IMO `split ";"` is misleading and should be avoided: the first argument to `split` is a regexp (except for the special magic case of `split " "`), even if you write it as a string.

Comment: I've changed the `split`. It is potentially misleading. I've also changed the double shift to splice. However, I am keeping where I set the hash to a null array reference. It both documents what I expect the hash value to be (a reference to an array), and it prevents me from accidentally setting it to a hash reference if I put in the wrong first value.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest (standard) way to do this is [`List::MoreUtils::natatime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils#natatime)

```
use List::MoreUtils qw<natatime>;
my $iter = natatime 2 => split /;/, 'xyz;1;xyz;2;a;2;b;2';
my %hash;
while ( my ( $k, $v ) = $iter->()) { 
    push @{ $hash{ $k } }, $v;
}
```

However abstracting out the parts that I would probably want to do again...

```
use List::MoreUtils qw<natatime>;

sub pairs { 
    my $iter = natatime 2 => @_;
    my @pairs;
    while ( my ( $k, $v ) = $iter->()) { 
        push @pairs, [ $k, $v ];
    }
    return @pairs;
}

sub multi_hash {
    my %h;
    push @{ $h{ $_->[0] } }, $_->[1] foreach &pairs;
    return wantarray ? %h : \%h;
}

my %hash = multi_hash( split /;/, 'xyz;1;xyz;2;a;2;b;2' );
```